# Is Linkle the daughter of Ilia and Link?

Tags: the-legend-of-zelda

Linkle uncannily looks like Ilia and Link. Is she their offspring?

[image: Ilia + Link = Linkle?]

Comment: "*During the development of Hyrule Warriors, Linkle was originally designed as a female version of Link. She was also proposed to be Link's little sister, but the idea was scrapped due to Eiji Aonuma not wanting her to conflict with Aryll, Link's sister in The Wind Waker. Sketches of her were included in the Hyrule Warriors art book from the Japanese limited editions of the game. Thanks to this, Linkle grew in popularity among fans, convincing the developers to include her in the game.*" - https://zelda.gamepedia.com/Linkle

Comment: Wikipedia claims she's Rusl's granddaughter, but I've found nothing to back that up.

Comment: @Harabeck I'd already [taken the liberty of removing it](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Linkle&action=history) by the time you commented, but it seems Google has cached the old version of the page.

Comment: Is there anything you have to suggest beyond what you think is an uncanny appearance? To me Llia looks way more clearly the daughter of Zelda, personally.

Comment: @TylerH - Because she's wearing a green hoodie?

Comment: @Valorum Because she looks like Zelda but with a green hoodie and Link's blonde hair.

Answer (score 1):

The Zelda IP exists across multiple continuities, a fact that [Hyrule Warriors](https://zelda.gamepedia.com/Hyrule_Warriors) (and/or Legends) exploits in its backstory (emphasis mine)

> Long ago, Ganondorf was defeated and his soul splintered into four fragments. Three of them were were sealed in different moments in time, while the fourth was trapped by the Master Sword. But Ganondorf plots his resurrection through Cia, a sorceress who protects the balance of the Triforce while maintaining neutrality. Cia becomes fascinated with the spirit of the Hero of Legend, with her amorous feelings for the hero providing Ganondorf an opportunity to purge her inner light. As a result, Cia becomes consumed in her desires, opening the Gate of Souls, **a portal to different time-space realities of Hyrule**, to amass an army of monsters. Seeking to unite the Triforce and conquer Hyrule, she uses her subordinates Volga and Wizzro to wage war against Princess Zelda and the Hyrulean army.

Ilia comes from the [Twilight Princess continuity](https://zelda.fandom.com/wiki/Ilia), but [Linkle's village](https://zelda.fandom.com/wiki/Linkle%27s_Village) clearly does not exist there, since [Linkle has to travel to that era](https://zelda.fandom.com/wiki/Linkle#Era_of_Twilight:_Her_True_Self) as part of the game. As such, it is not possible that she could be Linkle's mother (at least not the Twilight Princess version of her). Since we know nothing of Linkle's parents, it's still possible that her reality has some other version of Ilia.